# Transmission RPC access issues, but RPC web interface works

Tags: debian, transmission

My transmission RPC interface has started acting odd, by denying clients trying to access transmission via RPC, when setting.json indicate that should not be the case.

I was using Android clients such as Torrnado and Transdrone to access my transmission server on my private home network without issue.

While making some config changes I accidentally overwrote settings.json, and eventually had to restore to Debian default.

Afterwards, no applications can access transmission, citing an access denied error message. My settings.json file is not blocking anything, nor is it a firewall or credential issue.

I know this because access transmission on port 9091 will fail with an access denied message from applications, but accessing the RPC web interface works without issue on the same devices used to try and access transmission via RPC. RPC password is blank, but still gets hashed by transmission.

I also see no errors in the transmission or systemd logfiles.

My settings.json:

```
{
    "alt-speed-down": 50, 
    "alt-speed-enabled": false, 
    "alt-speed-time-begin": 540, 
    "alt-speed-time-day": 127, 
    "alt-speed-time-enabled": false, 
    "alt-speed-time-end": 1020, 
    "alt-speed-up": 50, 
    "bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0", 
    "bind-address-ipv6": "::", 
    "blocklist-enabled": false, 
    "blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist", 
    "cache-size-mb": 4, 
    "dht-enabled": true, 
    "download-dir": "/Media/Downloaded", 
    "download-limit": 100, 
    "download-limit-enabled": 0, 
    "download-queue-enabled": true, 
    "download-queue-size": 5, 
    "encryption": 1, 
    "idle-seeding-limit": 30, 
    "idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false, 
    "incomplete-dir": "/tmp/transmission/", 
    "incomplete-dir-enabled": true, 
    "lpd-enabled": false, 
    "max-peers-global": 200, 
    "message-level": 1, 
    "peer-congestion-algorithm": "", 
    "peer-id-ttl-hours": 6, 
    "peer-limit-global": 200, 
    "peer-limit-per-torrent": 50, 
    "peer-port": 51413, 
    "peer-port-random-high": 65535, 
    "peer-port-random-low": 49152, 
    "peer-port-random-on-start": false, 
    "peer-socket-tos": "default", 
    "pex-enabled": true, 
    "port-forwarding-enabled": false, 
    "preallocation": 1, 
    "prefetch-enabled": 1, 
    "queue-stalled-enabled": true, 
    "queue-stalled-minutes": 30, 
    "ratio-limit": 2, 
    "ratio-limit-enabled": false, 
    "rename-partial-files": true, 
    "rpc-authentication-required": false, 
    "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0", 
    "rpc-enabled": true, 
    "rpc-password": "{90996016d3d388d429100a67344d3e231f53f9d3q1TWzQ.5", 
    "rpc-port": 9091, 
    "rpc-url": "/transmission/rpc/", 
    "rpc-username": "admin", 
    "rpc-whitelist": "192.168.0.*", 
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": true, 
    "scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true, 
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": true, 
    "script-torrent-done-filename": "/etc/transmission-daemon/run_script.sh", 
    "seed-queue-enabled": false, 
    "seed-queue-size": 10, 
    "speed-limit-down": 100, 
    "speed-limit-down-enabled": false, 
    "speed-limit-up": 100, 
    "speed-limit-up-enabled": false, 
    "start-added-torrents": true, 
    "trash-original-torrent-files": false, 
    "umask": 18, 
    "upload-limit": 100, 
    "upload-limit-enabled": 0, 
    "upload-slots-per-torrent": 14, 
    "utp-enabled": true
}
```